# AD Security Groups Not Working

Tags: permissions

In SP2013, I want to grant permissions through AD Security groups.  Some other groups are working fine, but I'm trying to give the group proper rights to make changes to their things & get alerts, and read access for all others on the intranet.  I can explicitly give a user to this list Contribute rights and they can then receive the email alerts.  If I add the Security group to that list and wait based on the values below, they will not receive the alerts I subscribed them too.  I even waited overnight and still they were not receiving alerts this morning.  Anybody have any more thoughts or ideas?

```
LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow = 00:02:00
WindowsTokenLifetime = 00:05:00
FormsTokenLifetime = 00:05:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the PowerShell changes didn't do it for me so I tried this below and it worked.  I set it to 5 (with the POSH changes set as they were) and got expired messages, so then set it to 10 minutes.

```
STSADM.EXE -o setproperty -pn token-timeout -pv 10
```